# How to show 404 Page when user is typing any URL on login page if user is not authenticated?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want user to be blocked by accessing invalid URL from login screen if user is not authenticated, for instance, consider user is on login screen and if user tries to access any random url `localhost:3000/kanskd`, he/she should be redirected to login screen. I am able to achieve what i need by placing `NoMatch` route component, however, it matches the route inside my application as well and it renders No match for those routes as well[Routes that i am mapping after NoMatch route does not work].

> index.js

```
import Routes from './routes'

   <Switch>
       <Route exact path="/" render={() => {
          if(!store.getState().login.isAvailable) {
            return <Redirect to="/login"/>
          } else {
            return <Redirect to="/dashboard" />
          }             
        }} 
       /> 
       <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
       <Route component={NoMatch} />
       {Routes.map((prop, key) => {
          return <Route path={prop.path} key={key} component={prop.component} 
                  />;
       })}

   </Switch>
```

> NoMatch.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const NoMatch = ({ location }) => (
    <div>
      <h3>No match for <code>{location.pathname}</code></h3>
    </div>
)

export default withRouter(NoMatch);
```

EDIT:

> routes/index.js

```
import Dashboard from "Dashboard/Dashboard.jsx";

var Routes = [{ path: "/", name: "Dashboard", component: Dashboard }];

export default Routes;
```

Once the user logs in, it routes him to Dashboard and in Dashboard, there are other multiple routes.

Comment: Did you try adding `exact prop` on the `No match route` ?Is it possible for you to share your code in a `code sandbox`?

Comment: I did try with exact prop, it is still doing the same thing, let me check if i can setup a sandbox

Comment: Can you simply move `<Route component={NoMatch} />` to the last and see if it's working?

Comment: I tried that too, then random routes from login screen does not work :( @A.K.47

Comment: Please try to add a code sandbox so we get better clarity of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So you have to solve 2 things here: show the `NoMatch` component when there is no match for a url and protect some routes from not logged users.

For the first one you should put your `<Route component={NoMatch} />` just before the `<Switch>`closing tag, think of this like a switch in plain javascript, the last case is always the `default` case, if there is no other match the `default` will be executed, same as here.

The second problem requires a bit of extra code, you have to create a component that redirects the user if is not logged in, something like this (this is from the documentation react-router docs):

```
function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, isLoggedIn,...rest }) {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        isLoggedIn ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/login",
              state: { from: props.location }
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}
```

Then use this component for protected routes:

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" render={() => {
       if(!store.getState().login.isAvailable) {
         return <Redirect to="/login"/>
       } else {
         return <Redirect to="/dashboard" />
       }             
     }} 
    /> 
    <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
    {Routes.map((prop, key) => {
       return <PrivateRoute path={prop.path} key={key} component={prop.component} isLoggedIn={isUserLoggedIn} 
               />;
    })}
    <Route component={NoMatch} />
</Switch>
```

`isUserLoggedIn` is a made up variable, you should replace it for you logged in checks methods

**Edit:**
The path should be `/dashboard`:

```
import Dashboard from "Dashboard/Dashboard.jsx";

var Routes = [{ path: "/dashboard", name: "Dashboard", component: Dashboard }];

export default Routes;
```

if you want to maintain `/` as your path you should return the dashboard component inside your `Route` component instead of redirecting:

```
    <Route exact path="/" render={() => {
       if(!store.getState().login.isAvailable) {
         return <Redirect to="/login"/>
       } else {
         return <Dashboard/>
       }             
     }} 
    />
```

Comment: Hey thank you, now it is not routing to home page after login :(

Comment: is your home `/dashboard` ?